# Normalizing different data frame histograms and plot together

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, normalization

I have got 4 data frames of different lengths (672000, 240000, 1600000,1940000).

What I wish is to represent 4 histograms in the same graph. To do that I used this method:

```
#1º. I create a data frame with the data of interest.    
dat1 = data.frame(x=distances_298$V1, group="alpha298")
dat2 = data.frame(x=distances_318$V1, group="alpha318")
dat3 = data.frame(x=distances_ext_278$V1, group="ext278")
dat4 = data.frame(x=distances_ext_298$V1, group="ext298")

#I use rbind.fill to bind data frames that don't have the same set of columns 
library(plyr)
dat <- rbind.fill(dat1,dat2,dat3,dat4)

# Normalize histogram. 
ggplot(dat, aes(x, fill=group, colour=group)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..)), breaks=seq(0,15,0.1), alpha=0.6, 
  position="identity", lwd=0.1) +
  labs(x=expression(d["HB"]), y="Frecuency")  + geom_vline(xintercept = 2.5, colour="red") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.01, 0), breaks = seq(0, 15, 2.5), limits = c(0,15)) +
  scale_y_continuous( limits = c(0,0.025), breaks = seq(0,0.025,0.005)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue", "yellow")) + 
  ggtitle("(A)") +
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.position = c(0.9, 0.8), legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = -0.1, vjust=2.12))
```

What I get from this code is:

[image]

However, as you can see, the data are not normalized between 0-1, specifically the data alpha318

In this link you have the data what I'm using: [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rjv0uwjdglfag6g/data.RData?dl=0)

EDIT:

Using geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..))

[image]

Comment: I would suggests normalising the data beforehand, you can use for instance  `rescale` function :)

Comment: @JanSila I want to normalize the Y-axis, not the X axis.

Comment: please show your data using `dput()` rather than a link.

Comment: @Jimbou As I said, one of my data frame has got 1940000 obs of 8 variables. If I use dput(), the size will be very large.

Comment: Use `geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..))` or consider using `geom_density` instead. The area under the curve of the density function is 1 for each of the groups. Your axis limits may change the results. If this doesn't solve, please consider making a _minimal_ reproducible example, without us having to download files.

Comment: @Axeman Yes, that works, but as you said, the axis limits changed, so... What can I do to scale between 0 and 1? 

I edited the text and added the figure obtained.

Comment: A density function is defined as that the integral (or area under the curve) over the range of the data equals 1. So your groups are on a common scale; all their density functions integrate to 1. Not sure what you're after.

Comment: @Axeman Using `y=..density..` scales the histograms so the area under each is 1, or sum(binwidth * y)=1. As a result, I used y = binwidth *..density.. to have y represent the fraction of the total in each bin. In my case, binwidth=0.1.

Thank you very much, your help was really useful